# Python exec() command working in IDLE, not in program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I want to re-assign the value of a variable chosen by the user. The idea is that, if the user chooses this variable, the value of that variable is set to zero.

The code looks like this:

```
v1 = 8.4
v2 = 12.1
v3 = 36.2

list = ['', 'v1=', 'v2=', 'v3=']

print("What v do you want to be zero?")
print("    1 = v1")
print("    2 = v2")
print("    3 = v3")
a = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))
```

(the user enters 1)

```
b = list[a] + '0'
exec(b)
print(v1, v2, v3)
```

When I enter this code in IDLE, line by line, I get:

```
0 12.1 36.2
```

But, when I run the identical code within a function (*so the exec() and print(v1,v2,v3) statements are inside the same function), I get:

```
8.4 12.1 36.2
```

Can anyone explain this? I think it's probably a terrible way to do what I'm doing (I'm new to coding), and I welcome your suggestions on how to do it better, maybe a loop or a series of 'if/elif' statements? However, what I'd really like to know is why this code works when it's entered line-by-line, but not as a function.

(* = edit)

This is a program that does not re-assign any variable:

```
# delete me.py

def main():

    v1 = 8.4
    v2 = 12.1
    v3 = 36.2

    list = ['', 'v1=', 'v2=', 'v3=']

    print("What v do you want to be zero?")
    print("    1 = v1")
    print("    2 = v2")
    print("    3 = v3")
    a = eval(input("Enter your choice: "))

    b = list[a] + '0'
    exec(b)

    print(v1, v2, v3)

main()
```

Comment: You **really** want to avoid `exec` and `eval`. Your program could be rewritten to use a `dict` (`values = {'v1': 8.4, 'v2': 12.1, 'v3': 36.2}`), `int()` to take user input, and `lst = list(values)`, then `values[lst[a - 1]] = 0` and `print(values['v1'], values['v2'], values['v3'])`.

Comment: What about showing us the complete, non-working program? Then we can see how things really are...

Comment: Yeah I'm learning that eval and exec should be used carefully and sparingly. I suppose the user could enter and run any code he or she wants via that input, even if it has nothing to do with the purpose of my program. I hadn't thought of using dict keys stored in a list to re-assign dict values. That's way better than what I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is that you aren't allowed to modify variables through exec. It will sometimes work, but its not really allowed, and its never a good idea.

For this piece of code, you should write:

```
v = [8.4, 12.1, 36.2]
print("What v do you want to be zero?")
print("    1 = v1")
print("    2 = v2")
print("    3 = v3")
a = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
v[a - 1] = 0
print(v)
```

Basically, if you need to lookup a variable by user input, it should be in a list or dictionary. You should never need to do this for local variables.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Yeah, I thought I might be admonished for using exec() and eval() like I did, but I still wanted to know what was happening. Thanks for your explanation and suggestion. I will use a dict and int() instead of exec and eval.

Comment: Useful note from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec): "Note: The default locals act as described for function locals() below: modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns."

Comment: It used to be the case that `exec` would cause variable lookup within the same scope to use a different opcode (`LOAD_NAME` rather than `LOAD_FAST` or `LOAD_GLOBAL`), so you actually could change the locals and even create new local variables, but now that `exec` is a function, the compiler can't do that.

Comment: user2357112, thanks for pointing me to that. I need to figure out what default, function and explicit locals are. I've been programming for <6 months, so the documentation is still a tough read for me. I read the documentation about exec before posting this question and I figured something in there pertained to my problem, but I had no idea what a lot of it meant.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are updating the local scope of the function inside which you `exec` is run.

Compare this:

```
v = 42
def f(): v = 43 #which is inside you exec
f()
print(v)
```

Comment: My print statement is inside the function that contains the exec(). If, in your example, you put the print(v) into the f(), calling f() returns v = 43.

Comment: @user3103237 f doesn't return anything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if you put the print statement into f, the f() _prints_ 43, and not 42. In the code for my function above (I added it after you answered my question), the print statement is inside the function that also contains exec.